# Edit listview items

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i want to edit the selected item which is inserted in my listview. But i have a change tool in the menu. So i want the other Form (Form2) to appear when i press "change" in menu and the information in each textbox occur in its textbox (so I do not write it again because I only want to change something specific) and i can change the text depending on which textbox i want to change, as soon as i press "ok" button then the changes occur

Form1 = listview and the items
Form2 = the textboxes

Here is some code

Form1

```
        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColumnHeader columnheader;
        ListViewItem listviewitem;
        listView1.LabelEdit = true;

        // Ensure that the view is set to show details.
        listView1.View = View.Details;            

        // Create seven column headers for sorting the data. 
        ColumnHeader header1, header2, header3, header4, header5, header6, header7, header8, header9, header10;
        header1 = new ColumnHeader();
        header2 = new ColumnHeader();
        header3 = new ColumnHeader();
        header4 = new ColumnHeader();
        header5 = new ColumnHeader();
        header6 = new ColumnHeader();
        header7 = new ColumnHeader();
        header8 = new ColumnHeader();
        header9 = new ColumnHeader();
        header10 = new ColumnHeader();

        header1.Text = "ID";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header1);
        header1.Width = 50;

        header2.Text = "First name";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header2);
        header2.Width = 110;

        header3.Text = "Last name";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header3);
        header3.Width = 110;

        header4.Text = "Home phone";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header4);
        header4.Width = 120;

        header5.Text = "Cell phone";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header5);
        header5.Width = 110;

        header6.Text = "Country";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header6);
        header6.Width = 110;

        header7.Text = "Zip-code";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header7);
        header7.Width = 100;

        header8.Text = "City";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header8);
        header8.Width = 110;

        header9.Text = "Street";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header9);
        header9.Width = 110;

        header10.Text = "Email";
        this.listView1.Columns.Add(header10);
        header10.Width = 150;

        using(var customerframe = new CustomerFrame())
        {
            //if button OK is clicked then value will be inserted
            if (customerframe.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
            {
                CustomerFiles.Contact contact = customerframe.GetContact();
                CustomerFiles.Address address = customerframe.GetAddress();
                CustomerFiles.Phone phone = customerframe.GetPhone();
                CustomerFiles.Email email = customerframe.GetEmail();

                //Items in my listview
                listviewitem = new ListViewItem();
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(contact.FirstName);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(contact.LastName);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(phone.Home);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(phone.Mobile);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.Country);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.ZipCode);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.City);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.Street);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(email.Personal);

                this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Form2

```
        internal CustomerFiles.Contact GetContact()
    {
        CustomerFiles.Contact contact = new CustomerFiles.Contact();
        contact.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
        contact.LastName = tbLastName.Text;

        return contact;

    }
    internal CustomerFiles.Address GetAddress()
    {
        address.City = tbCity.Text;
        address.Street = tbStreet.Text;
        address.ZipCode = tbZipCode.Text;
        address.country = cbCountry.Text;

        return address;
    }
    internal CustomerFiles.Phone GetPhone()
    {
        CustomerFiles.Phone phone = new CustomerFiles.Phone();
        phone.Home = tbHomePhone.Text;
        phone.Mobile = tbCellPhone.Text;

        return phone;

    }
    internal CustomerFiles.Email GetEmail()
    {
        CustomerFiles.Email email = new CustomerFiles.Email();
        email.Personal = tbEmail.Text;

        return email;
    }
```

Comment: where is the Click Event code for the Menu Selection Change..? that's where you would want to implement the code..

Answer (score 0):

I really think you need something like a dataGridView but with list appearance, don't u?

Comment: i actually prefer the listview